# (Mac) Passing string args from VBA to dylib - empty string received in C++ function

Tags: c++, objective-c, vba, macos, dylib

Trying to call a C++ function (compiled in a dylib) from VBA and pass a string to it as follows -

**.h**

```
extern "C"
{
int func(const char* &str);
}
```

**.cpp**

```
int func(const char* &str)
{
//something something
}
```

**VBA**

```
Declare PtrSafe Function func Lib "<LibPath>" (ByRef str As String) As Integer
...
Function outFunc
   Dim str As String
   str = "Hello"
   func (str)
End Function
```

On Debugging the C++ code, the function is hit correctly, but an **empty string** is received in the 'str' variable.
Also used the nm utility to confirm that the function is exposed correctly from the dylib.

Comment: try to pass an array of bytes instead of string : Dim str as String
Dim ArrayOfBytes() As Byte

str = "yourString"
ArrayOfBytes() = str

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the type of your function parameter is correct. I think it will work if you change the C parameter to `const char* str` and define it in VBA as `ByVal str As String`.

See
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/810282/microsoft-office-vba-to-the-macs